# Can the player have a heavier weight?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gravity, collider

My question is maybe unclear, but I'll explain it through the picture I attached.
So, what I'm asking is, how can I have the player get more affected by the gravitation, so it falls off when only a small part is colliding?
I tried to increase the mass, but nothing changed by that.
Answers are appreciated!

[image]

Even if I scale the box collider down to the minimum, nothing changes.
[image]

Comment: Did you maybe constrain the Z rotation?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution. I had to freeze then unfreeze the rotation on the Z axis inside the rigidbody component. Might have been a smal little bug or something. Thank you all for the answers!

Answer (score -1):

To clarify your title: You don't seem to want "heavier weight", you want the center of gravity to actually matter.

Assuming you don't want to implement this logic yourself, you need to attach a [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) to your player object.

The collider components don't perform physics simulation, only collision evaluation.

Rigidbodies are generally not the default option because if you go this route, you have to be more careful with general physics interaction between your player and other objects. I'm fairly certain the default `PlayerController` also won't function with a `Rigidbody`, so you will have to reimplement that as well.

Comment: Sure I have rigidbody on the player object. I even said that I tried to increase the mass value, which is in the rigidbody component.

Comment: Then post screenshot of your collider bounds, they seem to be off.

Comment: Basically, almost the full width of the car. Not wider. I attached a picture of it into my question,.

Comment: what about the coliider of the road? Same thing?

Comment: If I make both the platforms and the players collider thinner, the edge of the player (car) will go through the platform which doesn't look great.

Comment: Please show the RigidBody settings